# CSS Fading Slider Focusing On Image 4

Tags: html, css, slider

The CSS fading slider that I'm editing on CodePen is somehow concentrating on the 4th image.  The title of All of the images is the title of the 4th image, and the URL for All of the images is the URL of the 4th image.  I've Never experienced anything like that before.  Anybody have a clue as to what's causing that?  Thanks!  :--)

```
https://codepen.io/FavorMan/pen/PoBqLyP
```

```css
.fade-slider-1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* position: relative; For Left Align - margin: 0 auto; For Center Align */
  /*position: relative;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fade-slider-1>div {
  position: absolute;
  animation: move_slide2 16s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-slider-1>div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

.fade-slider-1>div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.fade-slider-1>div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.fade-slider-1>div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

@keyframes move_slide {
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes move_slide2 {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-slider-1">

  <div>
    <a href="https://Metager.org" target="_blank"><img src="https://place-hold.it/250x250/C0C0C0/4169E1.png&text=Image-01&bold&fontsize=30" alt="IMAGE 1" title="IMAGE 1"></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="https://Quant.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://place-hold.it/250x250/C0C0C0/663399.png&text=Image-02&bold&fontsize=30" alt="IMAGE 2" title="IMAGE 2"></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="https://search.Brave.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://place-hold.it/250x250/C0C0C0/4169E1.png&text=Image-03&bold&fontsize=30" alt="IMAGE 3" title="IMAGE 3"></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="https://StartPage.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://place-hold.it/250x250/C0C0C0/663399.png&text=Image-04&bold&fontsize=30s" alt="IMAGE 4" title="IMAGE 4"></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty obvious in this case.

You're using the `position: absolute` on all of your `.fade-slider-1>div`.
So all your boxes are overlaying on top of each other, hence the last one that is positioned on top of them all.

[image]

Adding a `z-index` should resolve it like so:

```css
.fade-slider-1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* position: relative; For Left Align - margin: 0 auto; For Center Align */
  /*position: relative;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fade-slider-1>div {
  position: absolute;
  animation: move_slide2 16s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.fade-slider-1>div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

.fade-slider-1>div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.fade-slider-1>div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.fade-slider-1>div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

@keyframes move_slide2 {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-slider-1">

  <div>
    <a href="https://Metager.org" target="_blank"><img src="https://place-hold.it/250x250/C0C0C0/4169E1.png&text=Image-01&bold&fontsize=30" alt="IMAGE 1" title="IMAGE 1"></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="https://Quant.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://place-hold.it/250x250/C0C0C0/663399.png&text=Image-02&bold&fontsize=30" alt="IMAGE 2" title="IMAGE 2"></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="https://search.Brave.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://place-hold.it/250x250/C0C0C0/4169E1.png&text=Image-03&bold&fontsize=30" alt="IMAGE 3" title="IMAGE 3"></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="https://StartPage.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://place-hold.it/250x250/C0C0C0/663399.png&text=Image-04&bold&fontsize=30s" alt="IMAGE 4" title="IMAGE 4"></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I added (z-index: 0;) as suggested.  It still runs the same.  I Turned Off (position: absolute), and then it was stuck on image 1.  So I turned back on (position: absolute).  What would be better than (position: absolute)?   Thanks!  :--)

Comment: Check the code I've written under “Show code snippet” you're missing the solution here. I have added two other `z-index` in the `@keyframes move_slide2` check it out.

Comment: Yep, when I looked again at your addition to the code, I noticed that.  It runs Great now.  Thanks!  It's Past my bedtime again!  :--)